# Using ansible assert module with Jinja template fails

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to write a playbook with the intention of validating our current configuration of our network infrastructure.

To do this, I am using the following ansible modules:

ios_command - to pull configuration from the devices and register the output in a variable.
ansible.builtin.assert - to validate the running config to our "desired state" configuration in ansible inventory group_vars
Jinja lookup() to pull the template in assert module

I wanna do it with a Jinja template to loop over the inventory, and then assert it with a variable.

As a test I only wanna validate the name of our class-maps on the Cisco device:

ANSIBLE

```
    - name: Get running class-map config
      tags:
        - policy
      vars:
        ansible_connection: network_cli
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - 'sh run | in class-map match-any'
      register: show_policy
```

```
    - name: Validate running class-map with acl
      ignore_errors: yes
      tags:
        - policy
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        quiet: yes
        that:
          - "'{{lookup('template', 'test_policy.j2')[:-1]}}' in show_policy.stdout"
        success_msg: "TEST: {{ UNIT_HOSTNAME }}: VALIDATE RUNNING POLICY: PASSED"
        fail_msg: "TEST: {{ UNIT_HOSTNAME }}: VALIDATE RUNNING POLICY: FAILED"
```

JINJA TEMPLATE:

```
#jinja2: lstrip_blocks: False, trim_blocks: True
{% for classmap in CLASS_MAP %}
class-map match-any {{classmap.NAME}}
{% endfor -%}
```

I get the following error when running the playbook:

```
failed. The error was: Invalid conditional detected: EOL while scanning string literal (<unknown>, line 1)"}
```

FULL output from ASSERT module:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check ''class-map match-any CM-QOS-1P3Q-Q1\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-1P3Q-Q2\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-1P3Q-Q3\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-FREQUENCY-CONVERTER-REALTIME-MARK\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-GENERIC-BESTEFFORT-MARK\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-GENERIC-SCAVENGER-MARK\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-STC-1-REALTIME-MARK\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-STIC-SIMATIC-REALTIME-MARK' in show_policy.stdout' failed. The error was: Invalid conditional detected: EOL while scanning string literal (<unknown>, line 1)"}
```

And when printing the output from the template and ios_command, it seems to be exactly the same as the output from the ios_command when pulling the running config, except from the order.

```
TASK [Print output ios_command ] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok:  => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "stdout": [
            "class-map match-any CM-QOS-STC-1-REALTIME-MARK\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-GENERIC-BESTEFFORT-MARK\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-1P3Q-Q1\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-1P3Q-Q2\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-1P3Q-Q3\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-GENERIC-SCAVENGER-LIMIT\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-STIC-SIMATIC-REALTIME-MARK\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-GENERIC-SCAVENGER-MARK\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-FREQUENCY-CONVERTER-REALTIME-MARK"
```

```
TASK [show templating result from jinja ] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok:  => {
    "msg": "class-map match-any CM-QOS-1P3Q-Q1\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-1P3Q-Q2\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-1P3Q-Q3\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-FREQUENCY-CONVERTER-REALTIME-MARK\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-GENERIC-BESTEFFORT-MARK\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-GENERIC-SCAVENGER-MARK\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-STC-1-REALTIME-MARK\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-STIC-SIMATIC-REALTIME-MARK"
}
```

thanks in advance

Tried to render jinja to a variable and compare it, but it is the same result:

```
    - name: Render template to variable
      tags:
        - policy
      set_fact:
        template_var: "{{ lookup('template', 'test_policy.j2')[:-1] }}"
```

```
    - name: Validate running class-map with acl
      ignore_errors: yes
      tags:
        - policy
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        quiet: no
        that:
          - "'{{ template_var }}' in show_policy.stdout"
        success_msg: "TEST: {{ UNIT_HOSTNAME }}: VALIDATE RUNNING POLICY: PASSED"
        fail_msg: "TEST: {{ UNIT_HOSTNAME }}: VALIDATE RUNNING POLICY: FAILED"
```

Comment: Assertion are always templated, like `when` conditions: [_A list of string expressions of the same form that can be passed to the ‘when’ statement._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html), so, you at least need to remove the Jinja blocks: `{{ .. }}`: `- "lookup('template', 'test_policy.j2')[:-1] in show_policy.stdout"`

Comment: ---
*
fatal: [DKBB2-SWP-WTG001-TO-SW01]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "lookup('template', 'test_policy.j2')[:-1] in show_policy.stdout",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "TEST: DKBB2-SWP-WTG001-TO-SW01: VALIDATE RUNNING POLICY: FAILED"
---


That doesn't seem to do the trick. It doesn't run the template.

Also, when adding the template to a variable and using the variable in assert also fails.

  - "'{{ template_var }}' in show_policy.stdout[0]"

Comment: Your template just returns you a big string and `your_huge_template_string[-1]` means you just want the last character out of this templated thing, so this is probably not what you want. `show_policy.stdout[0]` doesn't make sense either, this is once again only one character. The best is that you debug what you are trying to do with `- debug: var=my_var` and not `- debug: msg="{{ my_var }}"`, so you'll have the exact same behaviour as your assertion.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε if I leave out the last [:-1] Jinja will add \n as the last character which will make the assert fail. This is why I have it in there.   <br/>  

Now doing debug: var: template_var - it has the same output as before:  <br/>    

The assert fails again even though the string is the exact same as the template_var  <br/>   

Short snippet   <br/>   

\nclass-map match-any CM-QOS-STIC-SIMATIC-REALTIME-MARK' in show_policy.stdout' failed. The error was: Invalid conditional detected: EOL while scanning string literal (<unknown>, line 1)"}  <br/>

Comment: Update assertion to - "'{{ template_var }}' in show_policy.stdout"

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

I used .splitlines() to add new lines in the list for the varible I create with set_fact to have multiple values in the list instead of 1 string containing all list values

Then simply loop over the list with assert module:

```
set_fact:
 template_var: "{{ lookup( 'template', 'test_policy.j2' ).splitlines() }}"

ansible.builtin.assert:
  quiet: no
  that:
    - "'{{item}}' in show_policy.stdout_lines[0]"
  success_msg: "TEST: {{ UNIT_HOSTNAME }}: VALIDATE RUNNING POLICY: PASSED"
  fail_msg: "TEST: {{ UNIT_HOSTNAME }}: VALIDATE RUNNING POLICY: FAILED"
loop: "{{ template_var }}"
```